# dynamically instantiating classes scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I am writing a program and as a requirement need to get all of the classes in a package, and need to return objects of them.

I have this code:

```
  package object cards {
  private val reflections: Reflections = new Reflections(
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("me.mysterymystery.duelingfactions.apiv2.guiindependant.card.cards"))
      .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner())
  )

  def getAllCards: Seq[Card] = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Card]).asScala.map(_.newInstance()).toSeq
   ...
  }
```

The card Class is:

```
trait Card {}
trait MonsterCard extends Card {}
```

then all cards extend from this trait, for example:

```
class ExampleCard extends MonsterCard
```

They have no constructors.
All cards are in the same package.

But get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.mysterymystery.duelingfactions.apiv2.guiindependant.card.MonsterCard.<init>()`

Does anybody have any ideas as to why and how to fix it?

Comment: What is that class?  Does it's constructor require parameters?

Comment: I've editted the post to say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonsterCard is a `trait`, not a `class` and can't be instantiated.  You will need to add some filtering so that you only get types that are concrete classes with appropriate constructors.